# How to troubleshoot the error code of "exc_bad_access(code=1,address=0x20)"

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access

I am experiencing a problem when my app executes a class function. The error code is:

> "EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x20)"

My source code with the problem is:

```
func setupClient(){
    let configuration = ConfigData.sharedInstance

    if (configuration.sipLogin == SipLoginStatus.SipLoginStatusLoggedOut && configuration.sipUsername?.length == 0) && (configuration.acsLogin == ACSLoginStatus.ACSLoginStatusLoggedOut && configuration.acsUsername?.length == 0){
        return
    }

    //the app is broken here with the code "exc_bad_access(code=1,address=0x20)" and CSClient is a Class imported by a third party framework.
    CSClient.setLogLevel(CSLogLevel.Debug)
    ...
}
```

[Here is the screenshot of the Xcode, when the app is broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0txM.png)

[I have added the Zoombie object option to check if there is any further findings, but no difference when the app is broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THWjA.png)

Can anyone advice how may I troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Do you have access to the implementation of `CSClient.setLogLevel` to show it?

Comment: The first thing I would check in this case would be the configuration.sipUsername?.length == 0 part of the previous condition.  if sipUsername happens to be nil, the condition could fail.  Depending on how the compiler optimized your code, it may be pointing at the following line of code (which is sometimes misleading but unavoidable)